# hangman input won't be read

Tags: java, netbeans

I've got a hangman assignment in java and most of my program works except when it tries to read the input and save it.  i only use string because i don't want to mess with converting char to string

my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean active = true;
    do
    {
        startGame();
        do
        {
            System.out.println("You have "+(numGuesses)+" guesses left");
            drawBoard();

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please enter your next guess: ");
            String mainGuess = input.nextLine();
            if ("stop".equals(mainGuess))
                currentState = End;//stops game if player chooses
            else
            {
                wordCondition(mainGuess);
                winLose();
            } 
        }
        while (currentState == Play);

        if (currentState == Win)
            System.out.println("Coongradulations you won!");  
        else if (currentState == Lose)
            System.out.println("Sorry, You lost");

        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? 1)yes 2)no");
        int answer=input.nextInt();
        active = (answer==1);
    }
    while (active);//creates a new game as much as user wants
}
```

and my problem block

```
public static void wordCondition(String guess)
{
    if (guess.contains(word))//check if letter is in word and substitutes the letter
    {
        board[guess.indexOf(word)]=guess;
        total++;
    }
```

and my drawing block

```
public static void drawBoard()
{
    System.out.println("Current word:");
    for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
        System.out.print(board[i]);
}
```

*for example the word is "name"
what i want*

You have 7 guesses left
Current word: _ _ _ _
Please enter your next guess: 
a

You have 7 guesses left
Current word: _ a _ _ 
Please enter your next guess:

*what i get*

You have 7 guesses left
Current word:_ _ _ _
Please enter your next guess: 
a

You have 6 guesses left
Current word:_ _ _ _ 
Please enter your next guess:

*or something like that, formatting is a little off
please help :)*

Comment: Time to lean how to use your IDE's debugger.

Comment: What problem is generated by your "problem block"?

Comment: Where and how is `board` defined?

Comment: need to post code for wordCondition(mainGuess);
                winLose();

Comment: Is `if (guess.contains(word))` condition actually right? It seems to me, it should be like,  `if (word.contains(guess))`.

Comment: @Aeshang `wordCondition` code is posted

Comment: @nIcEcOw Yup, that's it.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a wild guess, but isn't that code wrong?

```
public static void wordCondition(String guess)
{
    //check if letter is in word and substitutes the letter
    if (guess.contains(word))
        board[guess.indexOf(word)]=guess;
    else
        numGuesses--;
}
```

You are checking if the input letter contains word. You should be checking it the other way around:

```
public static void wordCondition(String guess)
{
    //check if letter is in word and substitutes the letter
    if (word.contains(guess))
        board[word.indexOf(guess)]=guess;
    else
        numGuesses--;
}
```

But this will substitute only one letter - if there will be two `a` then only one will be substituted. You should think of some other way to do that.

**SPOILER**

You can use this to substitute all letters. But you should really use char[] and change your approach for this:

```
public static void wordCondition(String guess)
{
    int position = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    for (char letter : word.toCharArray())
    {
        if (letter == guess.toCharArray()[0])
        {
            board[position]=guess;  
        }
        position++;
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        numGuesses--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ejaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaactly, my thought, on the topic :-) +1

Comment: @nIcEcOw - we've posted it at the same moment - I went for the answer instead of comment (had some doubts though;))

Comment: ive tried that but it keeps coming back as an error

Comment: @CJNotyou What error exactly? Isn't it substituted?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at exercise.pkg21.b.Exercise21B.wordCondition(Exercise21B.java:85)
 at exercise.pkg21.b.Exercise21B.main(Exercise21B.java:46)
Java Result: 1

Comment: ive tried everything ive learned in class and a lot of what i saw on the internet but nothing works, even my professor is stumped

Comment: @CJNotyou I've edited my answer. It was:
`board[guess.indexOf(guess)]=guess;` It should be:
`board[word.indexOf(guess)]=guess;`

Comment: ah, works now, thanks for the help, ill get to the one letter only thing now

Comment: @CJNotyou Glad I could help. You can always accept the answer if it solves your problem.
BTW - I've edited my answer so that it substitutes all letters.